# Display Time from mysql database DATETIME

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, time, strtotime

I am trying to display the date and time from the database. The problem with the time is that it is always changing its value and does not match with that one stored in the database.

PHP Code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `post_date`
                      FROM `private_section_posts`
                      WHERE `status` = 'show'");
while($post = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    $postdayofweek = date("D", strtotime($post['post_date']));
    $postday = date("d", strtotime($post['post_date']));
    $postsuffix = date("S", strtotime($post['post_date']));
    $postmonth = date("M", strtotime($post['post_date']));
    $postyear = date("Y", strtotime($post['post_date']));
    $posttime = date("g:ia", strtotime($post['post_date']));
    echo $postdayofweek . ' ' . $postday . $postsuffix . ' ' . $postmonth . ' ' . $postyear . 
    ' at ' . $time;

}
```

MYSQL post_date: 2014-01-28 04:00:00

Output Displayed: Tue 28th Jan 2014 at 10:36am

Comment: if you are storing correct time then just display which is a sub string datetime field.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL you can try like this

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(post_date,'%a %D %b %Y at %l:%i%p') FROM `private_section_posts`  WHERE `status` = 'show'
```

**Example**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%a %D %b %Y at %l:%i%p');
+---------------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%a %D %b %Y at %l:%i%p') |
+---------------------------------------------+
| Tue 28th Jan 2014 at 5:19PM                 |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to use `$posttime` variable instead of `$time`

```
$date = date("D d S M Y", strtotime($post['post_date']));   
$posttime = date("g:ia", strtotime($post['post_date']));
echo $date .' at ' . $posttime;
```

OUTPUT:

```
$date = date("D d S M Y", strtotime('2014-01-28 04:00:00'));    
$posttime = date("g:ia", strtotime('2014-01-28 04:00:00'));
echo $date .' at ' . $posttime;
    //output: Tue 28 th Jan 2014 at 4:00am
```

Comment: Still with the same problem